# How to get clicked option value when using multiple select with bootstrap-select with an on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I'm using bootstrap-select and I want to get only the clicked value of the `<option>` element when using `multiple` select

The following doesn't work (returns `undefined`):

```
$('#bootstrap-select').on('change', function (e) {
    let optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    console.log(valueSelected);
});
```

And the following gets all the selected options if multiple are chosen already:

```
$('#bootstrap-select').on('change',function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

But I want only the one clicked

Comment: Please add your HTML code

Comment: try: `let optionSelected = $("#bootstrap-select option:selected').text();`.